# How can I account for multiple standardized tests being used during a longitudinal study?

Tags: panel-data, psychometrics

I am currently conducting a longitudinal study of the growth of student test scores over time, and many of the districts in my study have switched to a new state assessment. The new assessment and the old one are obviously on two completely different scales.

My question is, what is the best way to account for this new assessment, so that I can still correctly measure student test score growth over time?

I was planning to simply normalize student test scores by transforming them into z-scores, but I don't believe I will have the state-level data required to perform this transformation. Are there any other studies that I could look at that have had to contend with this problem?

Comment: You've got a significant challenge ahead of you. Based on your description it sounds like your project is part of some Board of Education project or a dissertation. Either way, your work is likely to be scrutinized for its rigor and compliance with academic best practices and standards.  You will want to explore the educational literature on test psychometrics. I will get back with some suggestions

Comment: I greatly appreciate any literature you can point me to. I've done some searching on my own, obviously, but everything I've found is about standards-settings or test validity. So far nothing about linking one test to another in a longitudinal context.

Comment: You can do it IF you have some overlap, with scores on both tests fro some people. Sometimes this is called integrative data analysis - there was a special issue of the journal psychological methods on it, in 2009: http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/met/14/2/

Comment: One of the best resources for longitudinal "growth" studies is Singer's *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis*. It has a strong educational research bias with many references and a hierarchical modeling focus.    There's a paper by Heckman (the Nobel Laureate), et al., about a longitudinal study of the labor market impact of getting a GED. It tracks test changes over time with a methodology that might be appropriate for you. https://heckman.uchicago.edu/sites/heckman2013.uchicago.edu/files/uploads/Heckman_etal_2012_fthcmg_Easy%20Way%20Out.pdf